# how to open a program in python and send keystrokes?

Tags: python, pywin32

I want to open a browser, click on some fields and then send keystrokes.

The following code clicks at any point on screen.

```
win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,x,y,0,0)
win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,x,y,0,0)
```

Now i want to send keystrokes to that active application. How can i do that?

Comment: "I want to open a browser, click on some fields and then send keystrokes." Wouldn't scrapy do the job?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that library from Google code will do the job:
http://code.google.com/p/sendkeys-ctypes/

Check that link also for a sample code:

http://win32com.goermezer.de/content/view/136/254/

```
import win32com.client
shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
shell.Run("outlook")
shell.AppActivate("Outlook")
shell.SendKeys("^o", 0) # 1 für Pause = true 0 für nein
shell.SendKeys("^a", 0)
shell.SendKeys("^c", 0)
```

Comment: Thanks but here shell.Run("outlook") how to run any executable..where is "outlook" defined?

Comment: In that example, "Outlook" is an executable on the Environment variables (the PATH variable), but you can run any executable, batch file, etc... by specifying the full path as well.